# SSL imported across all computer accounts

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

**Background info**

Developed a web app that uses IIS8. Currently using IIS to perform client authentication. Server self-signs a certificate and the certificate is imported on specific PCs.

User access site from browser and browser prompts for SSL cert. (Cert is imported to Personal Folder).

For PCs with single accounts there is no issue as i just import the certificate to that account.

For PCs with multiple accounts, if i import the certificate to the Local Computer account the different accounts are unable to access the certificate.

**Query**

How do i allow multiple accounts to access a single certificate? Tried to grant individual permissions to the individual accounts from the Local Computer Certificates console but to no avail. I do not want to issue the certificate individually to each account.

Is there a solution or alternative to this query?

Comment: are you saying that you use server certificate for client authentication?

Comment: @CryptoGuy No, server self-signs a client certificate for authentication. I then import the self-signed client cert onto individual PCs.

Comment: the whole design is very bad. Each client must have its own client certificate. No shared certs. And instead of self-signed certificates, you should deploy your own centralized PKI and issue certificates to clients from centralized CA.

Comment: @CryptoGuy We view each client as the terminal not the the local computer account. Even if we deploy our own PKI and issue certs, still does not address the query on if 1 PC can have 1 certificate for all accounts. Is having a central certificate for each PC possible at all?

Comment: Doesn't matter how you treat them. Each terminal must be identified somehow and it is accomplished by issuing a unique client certificate to each terminal. Otherwise, all terminals are treated as single terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and separate *authentication* (using client certs) from account management, meaning *authorization*.

A good approach might be to use client certificates only to identify the user accessing your application (with exactly 1 certificate for each user). Then setup an n:m mapping to determine that user's *groups*, which in turn are given specific rights within your application. This is a common way to decouple users and their rights, to facilitate managing each.

Comment: The users are authenticated with username/password. The key item is that they want to ensure that only approved computers have the certificates and not so much of identifying different users.

Key thing here is to ensure the correct hardware is connecting. Your approach is good to have however i would just like to ensure that the correct hardware is connecting as i am controlling the user rights via the web application.